# How to properly switch the main domain on Magento 1.9?

Tags: payment, admin-url

We built a new Magento 1.9.4 store installing it fresh on www.mytestdomain.com. I've added and succussfully transferred my 2nd store from our Magento 1.9.1 installation. It worked fine.

Today, I tried to switch the main domain from our Magento 1.9.1 installation = www.myMAINdomain.com to our Magento 1.9.4 install. The way I did that was going into:

- System - Configuration - change Configuration Scope = Main Website --) general --) Web --) change Unsecure and Secure URL to:

https://www.myMAINstore.com/

**Now we have an issue with SSL certificates which I hope the hosting company will fix but more importantly when going through the order, after selecting the payment option and clicking on the CONTINUE button, the order DOES NOT actually continue to the 5. Order Review page.**

Also - the Admin panel is confused - it's still using the old URL of www.mytestdomain.com. How do I properly update the Admin panel URL?

---

**UPDATED on April 17th, 2019: After reading some articles, I disabled Form Key Validation On Checkout in Admin / Security Section and that made the Payment section work once again. 
The million dollar question is - is it OK to have the Form Key Validation disabled or do we need to have it enabled and why?**